# How to execute gcloud command in bash script from crontab -e

Tags: bash, cron, gcloud, cron-task, crontrigger

I am trying execute some gcloud commands in bash script from crontab. The script execute sucessfully from command shell but not from the cron job.

I have tried with:

1. Settng the full path to gcloud like:

   ```
    /etc/bash_completion.d/gcloud
    /home/Arturo/.config/gcloud
    /usr/bin/gcloud
    /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
   ```
2. Setting in the begin the script:

   ```
     /bin/bash -l
   ```
3. Setting in the crontab:

   ```
   51 21 30 5 6 CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2.7; 
   /home/myuser/folder1/myscript.sh param1 param2 param3 -f >> 
   /home/myuser/folder1/mylog.txt`
   ```
4. Setting inside the script:

   `export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python2.7`
5. Setting inside the script:

   `sudo ln -s /home/myuser/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud /usr/bin/gcloud`

Version Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
command to execute: `gcloud config set project myproject`

but nothing is working, maybe I am doing something wrongly. I hope you can help me.

Comment: is gcloud in your path for the user who's cron you've set?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the sudo ln... which SHOULD work (should). BUT, keeping in mind, you won't be authenticated...the cron environment won't be authenticated with `gcloud init` so you'll need to start off running something that will authenticate gcloud, probably with a service account would be the best way.

Comment: The first command that I executed is: gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=fileauth.json. How can i check if gcloud is in the path for the user in the cron? Need I too run "gcloud init" before?

Comment: gcloud init doesn't need to be run if you're doing the gcloud auth activate-service-account, that's enough. But you DO still need to set the project. Might that be it? Need to run `gcloud config set project my_project` after the activate-service-account call.

Comment: I found my error, the problem here was only in the command: "gcloud dns record-sets transaction start", the others command was executing sucesfully but only no logging nothing, by that I though that was not executng the other commands. This Command create a temp file ex. transaction.yaml and that file could not be created in the default path for gcloud(snap/bin), but the log simply dont write any thing!. I had to specify the path and name for that file with the flag --transaction-file=mytransaction.yaml. Thanks for your supprot and ideas

Comment: Oh good! There's no way in a million years I'd have found that. :D Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your user in your crontab, for it to run the gcloud command. As well explained in this other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30823604/google-cloud-sdk-code-to-execute-via-cron), you need to modify your crontab to fetch the data in your Cloud SDK, for the execution to occur properly - it doesn't seem that you have made this configuration.

Another option that I would recommend you to try out, it's using a Cloud Scheduler to run your gcloud commands. This way, you can use gcloud for your cron jobs in a more integrated and easy way. You can verify more information about this option here: [Creating and configuring cron jobs](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thanls gso_gabriel I read thats article but is the same result not working "crontab -u myuser -e" I read about cron scheduler but seem me that I need to knowk some language for  do it , this is a bash script only. I beleie only accept functions, pub/sub and app engine

Comment: I found my error, the problem here was only in the command: "gcloud dns record-sets transaction start", the others command was executing sucesfully but only no logging nothing, by that I though that was not executng the other commands. This Command create a temp file ex. transaction.yaml and that file could not be created in the default path for gcloud(snap/bin), but the log simply dont write any thing!. I had to specify the path and name for that file with the flag --transaction-file=mytransaction.yaml. Thanks for your supprot and ideas

Comment: Nice to hear it helped you! Please, consider upvoting my answer, if you think it helped you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I found my error, the problem here was only in the command: "gcloud dns record-sets transaction start", the others command was executing sucesfully but only no logging nothing, by that I though that was not executng the other commands. This Command create a temp file ex. transaction.yaml and that file could not be created in the default path for gcloud(snap/bin), but the log simply dont write any thing!. I had to specify the path and name for that file with the flag --transaction-file=mytransaction.yaml. Thanks for your supprot and ideas

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same issue before. I fixed it by forcing the profile to load in my script.sh,loading the gcloud environment variables with it. Example below:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /etc/profile
gcloud config set project myprojectecho 
echo "Project set to myprojectecho."
```

I hope this can help others in the future with similar issues, as this also helped me when trying to set GKE nodes from 0-4 on a schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below line to the shell script fixed my issue

#Execute user profile

source /root/.bash_profile