# gcloud doesn't execute via cron

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cron, gcloud

I want to implement an automated code to shut down VM Instances in my Google Cloud account via Crontab. I use Ubuntu 18.

I tried this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
source/etc/profile
echo Y | gcloud compute instances stop my-vm-name --zone us-central1-a
sleep 120s
echo "completed"
```

It's work mannually but when i add this code in cron

```
20 17 * * *  /bin/sh /home/user/Desktop/script.sh >>/home/user/cron.log
```

The VM doesn't stop in my GC compute engine. I made the answers to this question but, the rest does not work.

[Google cloud SDK code to execute via cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30823604/google-cloud-sdk-code-to-execute-via-cron)

Can anyone help?

Comment: 1) You can schedule shutdown in the Google Cloud Console GUI. Look under **INSTANCE SCHEDULE**.  2) Error here: **source/etc/profile** (missing space) 3) Do not specify programs in your home directory. Although CRON usually runs as root, bad practice. 4) What does **/var/log/cron.log** show?

Comment: Thanks for reply john ! 1) yes ikonw with INSTANCE SCHEDULE but i want to have a master instance to manage all my instance instead of making a sechdule instance for each instance. 3)                                                                                                      CRON[1735]: (root) CMD (/bin/sh /home/user/Desktop/Script.sh >>/home/user/cron.log)
CRON[1734]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Comment: There is no error message in cron.log or **/home/user/cron.log**? Note: Change the paths to not use your home directory. Next change the line to be like this **20 17 * * *  /bin/sh /home/user/Desktop/script.sh >>/home/user/cron.log 2>&1** This will send script error messages to  /home/user/cron.log. Cron errors will still go to /var/log/cron.log. One of them will tell you what is failing. Make the changes, try again and then update your question.

Comment: use absolute paths, or add paths in the context of the execution user

Comment: Thanks guys, it's worked. I changed the path and I find that gcloud doesn't find it, so I reinstalled the SDK to fix the problem.